# RecyclerView Lazy Loading (Universal Image Loader)

Tags: android, android-studio, lazy-loading, android-recyclerview, universal-image-loader

Using [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and RecyclerView to asynchronously load images, I'm getting the same error as other people, where the images get mixed up; until they have all loaded an are cached.

Code for the adapter:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.MemoryCacheUtils;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import romina.theftest.connectivity.ImgDownloader;

/**
 * Created by romin on 18/1/2016.
 */
public class ProductRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private List<Product> mValues;
    private Context mContext;
    private View.OnClickListener mListener;
    // Allows to remember the last item shown on screen
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private final String OLD_DOMAIN = "";
    private final String NEW_DOMAIN = "";

    public ProductRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, View.OnClickListener mListener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    public ProductRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Product> mValues, Context mContext, View.OnClickListener mListener) {
        this(mContext, mListener);
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, parent, false);

        Log.d(ProductRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "onCreateViewHolder");
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewHolder actualViewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        actualViewHolder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        actualViewHolder.mIdView.setText("" + mValues.get(position).getName());
        Log.d(ProductRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "onBindViewHolder pos " + position);

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
        final String finalImgURL = mValues.get(position).getImgURL().toString().replaceAll(OLD_DOMAIN, NEW_DOMAIN);
            imageLoader.displayImage(finalImgURL, actualViewHolder.mImgView);

        setAnimation(actualViewHolder.mContentView, position);
    }

    public void setDataSet(List<Product> newValues) {
        mValues = newValues;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues == null ? 0 : mValues.size();
    }

    /**
     * Here is the key method to apply the animation
     */
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final ImageView mImgView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public Product mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity_title);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity_title);
            mImgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity_image);

            mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (null != mListener) {
                        mListener.onClick(v);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

**I know it has to be something in `onBindViewHolder` , since it's called for updating every view but I'm not updating the `ImageView` properly.**

**It doesn't have to do with the library.** The same behaviour was happening when doing lazy loading without caching the images. The error is because I don't know how to update the `ImageView` in `onBindViewHolder` .

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, How you fix your issue? please share solution.I am having same issue. when i scroll Recyleview then UIL mixing-up/reloading different images with already loaded previous images.

Comment: @JasbirBhinder I did something similar to the accepted answer, but I now realize that it's better to use Picasso for it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you init the ImageLoader only once in the App.
Create a class and extend it with Application and then put in the AndroidManifest.xml like:

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
.../>
```

Application class

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024)
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    }
}
```

For `onBindViewHolder` which you want to know:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CategoryHolder holder, final int i) {

    holder.categoryImage.setImageBitmap(null);

    if (mRow.get(i).getImage() != null && !mRow.get(i).getImage().equals("")) {
        final File image = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(mRow.get(i).getImage(), imageLoader.getDiskCache());
        if (image!= null && image.exists()) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(image).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.categoryImage);
        } else {
            imageLoader.loadImage(mRow.get(i).getImage(), new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
                    holder.categoryImage.setImageBitmap(null);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, final Bitmap bitmap) {
                    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(s).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.categoryImage);

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

                }
            });
        }
    }else {
        holder.categoryImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    holder.categoryName.setText(mRow.get(i).getName().toUpperCase());

}
```

Comment: Though it worked (thanks!) do you know what is the correct way to update views in onBindViewHolder ? I know I will face the same issue with any other view sooner or later; but all examples I see are with TextViews, which are rather simple to update.

Comment: You need to init Imageloader only once in the Application class. I will update the code in some time.

Comment: Picasso & UIL together? could you please enlighten us and tell us why did you use Picasso & UIL  together?

Comment: @k0sh I am using UIL for caching and Picasso for Complex image transformations with minimal memory use. If it is wrong then please help me correct, as I am still exploring this area.

Comment: I didn't use Picasso, but @Keshav 's code in onCreate worked.

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer is at -1? It appears to have worked for the OP, but I don't know if there is any reason I shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @Jam The reason why it has -1 is because I am using 2 libraries, UIL and Picasso. Though in my implementation I am usinh UIL for image downloading and Picasso to handle image resizing recycling etc. I am ofcourse disabling and clearing picasso cache, because Picasso can store image in its own cache.

Comment: Why do you work with 2 different cache managers? Picasso and UIL? I doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is due to multiple instances of image loader:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

Try creating a single instance of the same for the adapter. Declare it with other class variables. You are creating multiple instances of image loader by calling it in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. The error wasn't caused by this, but you're right I shouldn't be getting the instance inside that method. Thanks!

Comment: You are right on the multiple instance, but that wont give any error. It's just that it will be called every time RecyclerView is scrolled.