# Recyclerview lazy loading with picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am loading all device images in recyclerview using Picasso lib but problem which i am facing in this is recyleview loading all image in one hit I want image will load when user scroll down not in one hit
Note:- I am using multiple recyleview because i am showing device image datewise

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ImageList imageList = imageLists.get(position);
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageView;
        File imgFile = new File(imageList.path);
        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(imgFile).resize(230, 100)
                    .centerCrop().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this method and scroll down the list. You should see that  the images are loaded as you scroll. It might be that they are loaded so quickly that you don't notice.

Comment: Refer following links once:https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/image-loading-recyclerview-picasso.html    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866965/recyclerview-lazy-loading-universal-image-loader